# ASP.NET WebForms Routing returns 404 resource not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, routes

I am trying to implement the following tutorial in my website:
[Simple blog tutorial with ASP.NET](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-Blog-Tutorial-with-example-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

The problem I am facing is with the URL Routing feature.

Before I ask this question, I have seen the first 5 pages of results from Google and also lots of questions from StackOverflow, but none of them seems to help.

Right now what I have is:

IIS version - 7
.NET Framework version - 4
IIS has the HTTP redirect feautre enabled.
IIS is not running in classic mode.

Web.config

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="UrlRoutingHandler" />
    </handlers>    
  </system.webServer>
```

Definition of the routing (RouteConfig.cs):

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("DisplayBlog", "Blogs/{BlogId}/{Slug}.aspx", "~/Blog/DisplayBlog.aspx");
    var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
    settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
    routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
}
```

How I try to open the blog post:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" 
   NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/Blogs/{0}/{1}.aspx", Eval("BlogId"), Eval("Slug")) %>'
   Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' runat="server" />
```

Pretty much everything looks as described in the tutorial except that whenever I try to open a blog post I get the following error:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>
> The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable

Any other suggestions that I may try?

Comment: Please post the actual link rendered as well as the URL you are redirected to (the one that causes the 404).

Comment: http://localhost/GECC/Blogs/2/jhgjhg

Comment: Shouldn't generated url have .aspx at end of it? I would suggest test it first using hardcoded url.